# Javascript function in HTML not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, get

**Dear Stackers**

I am having following issue. I want to make a Website, with only one HTML file, and insert the Content based on which **li element** got clicked. And a standard text should already be there.

---

Now my issue is, that it will not change the **value=""** of **id="content"**. It will not even writeContent for some reason. I am quite sure I am making a simple and fundamental mistake. I know that it is not yet optimized, but I need to get it working like this, before minimizing anything.

---

You can currently ignore the **function writeContent** part, since that will do the **innerHTML insertion** later on. - currently no Errors

```js
function myHome() {
  document.getElementById("content").value = "home_content";
  writeContent("<p>myHome</p>");
}

function myKontakt() {
  document.getElementById("content").value = "kontakt_content";
  writeContent("<p>myKontakt</p>");
}

function myTeam() {
  document.getElementById("content").value = "team_content";
  writeContent("<p>myTeam</p>");
}

function myUber() {
  document.getElementById("content").value = "uber_content";
  writeContent("<p>myUber</p>");
}

document.getElementById("home_li").addEventListener("click", myHome);
document.getElementById("kontakt_li").addEventListener("click", myKontakt);
document.getElementById("team_li").addEventListener("click", myTeam);
document.getElementById("uber_li").addEventListener("click", myUber);

function writeContent() {
  var get_content_attribute = document.getElementById("content").getAttribute("value");

  if (document.getElementById("content").getAttribute("value") == "home_content") {

  } else if (get_content_attribute = "kontakt_content") {

  } else if (get_content_attribute = "team_content") {

  } else if (get_content_attribute = "uber_content") {

  }
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" onclick="myHome()" id="home_li">Stalinger</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="" onclick="myKontakt()" id="kontakt_li">Kontakt</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="" onclick="myTeam()" id="team_li">Unser Team</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="" onclick="myUber()" id="uber_li">Über Uns</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="content" value="home_content">
  <p class="content_text">TEXT
  </p>

</div>
```

Comment: (I do currently not get any errors)

Comment: just get the script part out of the div with the ID : content. then change the value by innerHTML (document.getElementById("content").innerHTML= "your content"; )

Comment: use setAttribute as document.getElementById("content").setAttribute ("value","XXXXXX")

Answer (score 0):

You can check updated code:

To assign attribute you need to use *setAttribute* instead of *value*

```js
function myHome() {
  document.getElementById("content").setAttribute("value","home_content");
  writeContent("<p>myHome</p>");
}

function myKontakt() {
  document.getElementById("content").setAttribute("value","kontakt_content");
  writeContent("<p>myKontakt</p>");
}

function myTeam() {
  document.getElementById("content").setAttribute("value","team_content");
  writeContent("<p>myTeam</p>");
}

function myUber() {
  document.getElementById("content").setAttribute("value","uber_content");
  writeContent("<p>myUber</p>");
}

document.getElementById("home_li").addEventListener("click", myHome);
document.getElementById("kontakt_li").addEventListener("click", myKontakt);
document.getElementById("team_li").addEventListener("click", myTeam);
document.getElementById("uber_li").addEventListener("click", myUber);

function writeContent() {
  var get_content_attribute = document.getElementById("content").getAttribute("value");
alert(get_content_attribute);
  if (document.getElementById("content").getAttribute("value") == "home_content") {

  } else if (get_content_attribute = "kontakt_content") {

  } else if (get_content_attribute = "team_content") {

  } else if (get_content_attribute = "uber_content") {

  }
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myHome()" id="home_li">Stalinger</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myKontakt()" id="kontakt_li">Kontakt</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myTeam()" id="team_li">Unser Team</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myUber()" id="uber_li">Über Uns</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="content" value="home_content">
  <p class="content_text">TEXT
  </p>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the hint - I think you got me a bit wrong - I dont want to add any text in there yet. I only want to change the value, so i can change the text later :)

But thanks for the otherwise good effort :)

Answer (score 0):

1.Looks like div can't has value attribute, try to use "data-value"
    or something like that and everything will works fine.
 2. you are adding to event listeners on every button when using "click" in html and "addEventListener"  in js
 3. You should use "event.preventDefault()" to prevent page from reloading when pressing ""

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="" id="home_li">Stalinger</a></li>
                <li><a href="" id="kontakt_li">Kontakt</a></li>
                <li><a href="" id="team_li">Unser Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="" id="uber_li">Über Uns</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="content" data-value="home_content">
            <p class="content_text">TEXT
            </p>
            <script>
                function myHome(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    document.getElementById("content").setAttribute('data-value',"home_content");
                    writeContent("<p>myHome</p>");
                }
                function myKontakt(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    document.getElementById("content").setAttribute('data-value',"kontakt_content");
                    writeContent("<p>myKontakt</p>");
                }
                function myTeam(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    document.getElementById("content").setAttribute('data-value',"team_content");
                    writeContent("<p>myTeam</p>");
                }
                function myUber(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    document.getElementById("content").setAttribute('data-value',"uber_content");
                    writeContent("<p>myUber</p>");
                }

                document.getElementById("home_li").addEventListener("click", myHome);
                document.getElementById("kontakt_li").addEventListener("click", myKontakt);
                document.getElementById("team_li").addEventListener("click", myTeam);
                document.getElementById("uber_li").addEventListener("click", myUber);

                function writeContent(html) {
                    var div = document.getElementById("content");
                    var get_content_attribute = document.getElementById("content").getAttribute("data-value");

                    if(document.getElementById("content").getAttribute("data-value") == "home_content"){
                        div.innerHTML = html;
                    } else if(get_content_attribute = "kontakt_content"){
                        div.innerHTML = html;
                    } else if(get_content_attribute = "team_content"){
                        div.innerHTML = html;
                    } else if(get_content_attribute = "uber_content"){
                        div.innerHTML = html;
                    }
                }
            </script>
         </div>
     </body>
 </html>
```

this code is working for me, but architecture is pretty ugly, maybe try to read about how frontend frameworks manage this things.

Answer (score 0):

use setAttribute as document.getElementById("content").setAttribute ("value","XXXXXX") – by User: Vinod Louis

Worked like a charm.